# keytool -genkey runs in a loop to generate .keystore file

Tags: java, keytool

I invoked this on cmd:

```
keytool -genpair -v - keystore myrelease.keystore -keyalg RSA - keysize 2048 -validity 1000
```

The tool runs, asks the questions, and then loops again to the questions. It doesn´t generate the .keystore.

Please help. I can´t pass that loop to generate my .keystore.

I´ve given all permisions to java/bin folder, also changed the folder to C:/ but still runs in a loop after the last question. I type "y" and "yes" to confirm the .keystore creation but doesn´t generate one. Please help. 
Thanks.
What other permissions/setups do I need to check?

Comment: what is the question? not seeing any question mark!

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I asked (the obvious) question (edited). But what other things do I need to check out? Everything seems to point to permissions for R/W on the jre1.8.0_65/bin folder but I uncheck "read only", and I still get this error. What else should I check?

Answer (score 19):

KeyTool uses a locale-specific resource bundle for comparing your answer to the confirmation question with "yes"/"y". In other words: It expects the answer in the *same language as the question*.

For example in German:

```
  Ist CN=test, OU=Unknown, O=Unknown, L=Unknown, ST=Unknown, C=DE richtig?
  [Nein]:  ja
```

Answering in English ("*yes*") to the above question would have been interpreted by keytool as "*user did not confirm*" and therefore keytool would start over with the questions.

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH!!! 2 WEEKS STRAIGHT looking all around the web, this just nailed it!!! THANKS!!

Comment: Standards commands should be not based on the locale... Very annoying.

Comment: Had to use "sí", my computer was on Spanish 